# Firemonkey app: monospace font in TMemo?

Tags: fonts, firemonkey, delphi-xe

Is it possible to set/use a Monospace font in TMemo in a Firemonkey (developed with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo) application.

We tried:

```
TextSettings.Font.Family := 'Courier New';  
TextSettings.Font.Family := 'Courier';  
TextSettings.Font.Family := 'Monospace';
```

But when we run the app in Android the text font is not monospace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue in this way:

```
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
    Memo1.TextSettings.Font.Family := 'Courier New';
    Memo1.StyledSettings :=  Memo1.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Family]
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
    Memo1.TextSettings.Font.Family := 'monospace';
    Memo1.StyledSettings :=  Memo1.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Family]
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: For iOS 'Courier New' works

Answer (score 1):

First, don't do any application for android using Delphi Tokyo, it's not work yet and you app will be very very slow! you must wait an update.

This is all the font available on android :

```
// +---------------------------------------------------------------+
// ¦    ¦ FONT FAMILY                ¦ TTF FILE                    ¦
// ¦----+----------------------------+-----------------------------¦
// ¦  1 ¦ casual                     ¦ ComingSoon.ttf              ¦
// ¦  2 ¦ cursive                    ¦ DancingScript-Regular.ttf   ¦
// ¦  3 ¦ monospace                  ¦ DroidSansMono.ttf           ¦
// ¦  4 ¦ sans-serif                 ¦ Roboto-Regular.ttf          ¦ Roboto-Regular.ttf / Roboto-Bold.ttf / Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf / Roboto-Italic.ttf
// ¦  5 ¦ sans-serif-black           ¦ Roboto-Black.ttf            ¦ Roboto-Black.ttf / Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf
// ¦  6 ¦ sans-serif-condensed       ¦ RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf ¦ RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf / RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf / RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf / RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf
// ¦  7 ¦ sans-serif-condensed-light ¦ RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf   ¦ RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf /  RobotoCondensed-LightItalic.ttf
// ¦  8 ¦ sans-serif-light           ¦ Roboto-Light.ttf            ¦ Roboto-Light.ttf / Roboto-LightItalic.ttf
// ¦  9 ¦ sans-serif-medium          ¦ Roboto-Medium.ttf           ¦ Roboto-Medium.ttf / Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf
// ¦ 10 ¦ sans-serif-smallcaps       ¦ CarroisGothicSC-Regular.ttf ¦
// ¦ 11 ¦ sans-serif-thin            ¦ Roboto-Thin.ttf             ¦ Roboto-Thin.ttf / Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf
// ¦ 12 ¦ serif                      ¦ NotoSerif-Regular.ttf       ¦
// ¦ 13 ¦ serif-monospace            ¦ CutiveMono.ttf              ¦
// +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so try instead **serif-monospace**

Comment: Thank you! But I solved the issue in another way (see my anser). Do you think Delphi 10.2 Tokyo is much slower than Delphi 10.1 Berlin  ?

Comment: yes, see here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17162 ... don't forget to vote also :)